# Is running a TS (RDP) on a DC a very bad idea?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

For a project we only have one Windows Server available. We need to run both a TS (Terminal Server) with RDP and ADDS on this server. I have asked this question and got the answer that if we don't want a TS and DC on the same server, Hyper-V would be the solution. I have of course thought about this, however the Windows Server is running as a VPS and therefore using Hyper-V is not possible.

Therefore, I am wondering if running a TS and using the server as a DC at the same time would be a *really* bad idea. It's clear that Microsoft doesn't recommend it, but it's possible and therefore I have the idea that a lot of people think it is a security risk but not **that** big of a security risk. Is it?

About 5 to 10 users will have access to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Server 2012 and onwards windows prevents you installing both services on the same server successfully. We tried with 2012 and ended up with a partially installed set of services, as it lets you start the install but it crashes part way through. That is particularly annoying for what it does to the rest of the domain, with a partially installed DC joining the domain.

We did read about some registry hacks that would of allowed us to do both, but we decided against that, as we had the option of having separate VMs.

All of that being said, we have a number of 2008r2 servers with RDS and DC services on the same server for a bunch of our small remote branches with no ill effect for quite a few years of usage.

Comment: At the moment we don't need licensing, so I should've been a bit more clear: we are going to run simply RDP with the concept of a TS, however not a TS service itself though.

Comment: without the RDS service windows will limit you to 2 simultaneous sessions, which the EULA allows you to use for 'administrative' usage.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware...

Comment: I almost flagged this response for ugly truth. Man that is depressing they didn't do a check for conflicting roles.

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards: I realize that you're aware of the licensing implications, but if you intend on running applications from these sessions as opposed to performing administrative tasks from these sessions then you are clearly in violation of the EULA. If that's your intention then we can't in good conscience give you any answers that help you achieve your goal.